# How to enforce my Android web app to ask the user for a browser choice

Tags: android

How to enforce my Android web app to ask the user for a browser choice in which the application should be open.

EDITED : I will shed more light into what exactly i am planning to do. Actually i am using jquery mobile to add fixed toolbar function. But when i deploy it on the device i saw some flickering on the toolbar. So, i thought that maybe i should see how my app behaves when i deploy it to something else then opera. I am new to android and web dev so please TOLERATE ;)

Comment: How are you deploying your web app? Is it just a site that you host? If so the user will navigate to it in whatever browser they normally use, there is no need for you to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Users will choose how they want your link to open.